# Makefile Error: undefined reference to `zmq_connect'

Tags: c++, makefile, zeromq, flags

I have a C++ project that uses the zmq library. My project has the following files in the root folder:

```
main.cpp
app1.cpp app1.h
app2.cpp app2.h
```

I was previously creating the executable by running the following command:
g++ main.cpp app1.cpp app2.cpp -lzmq -o output

Now I want to create a Makefile for this project. My Makefile contains the following:

```
CFLAGS = -lzmq
all: main.o app1.o src/app2.o
    g++ -o main $(CFLAGS) main.o app1.o app2.o
clean:
    $(RM) main
```

When I run make, it gives me undefined references to the zmq function, which implies that it did not include the zmq library. How can I solve this issue?

P.S. I have not made a Makefile before and I created this one based on some tutorial articles.

Comment: Notice the difference in order `g++ main.cpp app1.cpp app2.cpp -lzmq -o output` vs `g++ -o main $(CFLAGS) main.o app1.o app2.o`. In the first the library is after the source files, but in the second the library is before the object files. This matters, `-lzmq` must go after the `*.o` files.

Comment: Since `CFLAGS` is normally used for compiler flags, not linker libraries, the best solution would be to replace `g++ -o main $(CFLAGS) main.o app1.o app2.o` with `g++ -o main main.o app1.o app2.o -lzmg`

Comment: @john Maybe add it as an answer so I can mark it as solved?